# How to fix: "The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading."?

Tags: 12.04, firefox, google-chrome

I have a 64-bit Ubuntu 12.04 installed. I used to login to a website (chess.com) but since a few days ago I get this message:

> The connection was reset
>
> The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading.
>
> The site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a
>   few moments. If you are unable to load any pages, check your
>   computer's network connection. If your computer or network is
>   protected by a firewall or proxy, make sure that Firefox is permitted
>   to access the Web. This is the case in Firefox, and chrome. A friend
>   of mine confirmed to me that the website is working fine and he could
>   access it. And I can access many other websites and facing no issues
>   except for this website.

I tried switching the use TLS 1.0 option as suggested by someone but this didn't fix it.

Can someone suggest a way to fix this issue?

Comment: Works fine for me with Chrome 21 on Ubuntu 12.04. What browser are you using?

Comment: Are you sure this site isn’t filtered in your country?

Answer (score 1):

Resolved this by clearing Cookies and Cache in Firefox.

1. In Firefox, at the top Menu go to History
2. Clear Recent History
3. In the Time Range to clear: drop-down, select Everything.
4. Click the arrow next to Details to display the list of items that can be cleared.
5. Select both Cookies and Cache (you can un-select others)
6. Click Clear Now.
7. Restart Firefox

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-cant-load-websites-other-browsers-can?esab=a&s=The+connection+was+reset&r=2&as=s#w_firefox-cannot-load-certain-websites